# Haskell: I don't know how to match types

Tags: haskell

So, I have this Haskell question to resolve:

Define a `mapIO` function that receives a function `f` and an input and output action `a` and results in an input and output action that, when executed, performs the given action `a` and returns the application of `f` to the return of `a`.

Here's my code:

```
mapIO f a = do b <- a
               return f(b);
```

It compiles but it doesn't work. When I try to do the same as the following execution example, it doesn't work. Please, can someone help me?

```
Prelude Data.Char> mapIO even readLn
75
False
```

Comment: What does not work? `75` is odd, so you get an `IO Bool` that is a `False` wrapped in an `IO`.

Comment: `return f(b);` should be `return $ f b` or `return (f b)`. @WillemVanOnsem I think that's meant to be the example output, not the actual output

Comment: `return f(b)` is parsed as `return f b`, i.e. the application of `return` to two arguments, `f` and `b`. `return` is not a keyword as you may expect (i.e. as in many imperative/OO languages) so it follows the normal rules of function application precedence.

Comment: It worked when I did return (f b). Sorry I'm really newbie using functional languages. Thank you guys, really!

Comment: I'm stumped at the inferred type of OP's `mapIO` despite understanding how it's parsed... Can anyone explain?

Comment: @ThiagoRoberto you're going about things the wrong way around; start by writing your type signature (then you won't have to write out things like that tortured second paragraph), then start on the implementation. Also use e.g. `:t mapIO` to query for the types of things in ghci

Comment: @jberryman Yes, I can explain. See my answer. =)

Comment: @jberryman actually it was the activity statement, anyway thanks for the tip, I'll try that more oftenly from now on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In many other languages, `g(x)` is the syntax for applying function `g` to argument `x`. In Haskell, juxtaposition suffices, so that `g x` applies `g` to `x`. By coincidence, this means `g(x)` is *also* valid syntax that applies `g` to the value `(x)`, which is the same as `x`, so to a beginner it may seem that `g(x)` is the correct syntax for function application. But it ain't, and that confusion has bitten you here.

When you write `return f(b)`, you probably assume this means to use the special syntax `return` and the thing to return should be the function application `f(b)`. However, `return` is itself a function in Haskell. So what it actually means is to apply `return` to the function `f`, then apply the result to the term `(b)`. (Function application is "left-associative" in that sense.)

Luckily the fix for function application associativity problems, as with other associativity problems, is to use parentheses. So:

```
return (f(b))
```

Or, without the coincidentally correct extra parentheses:

```
return (f b)
```

This leaves only the question of why it "worked" (in the sense of compiled and type-checked) in `return f(b)` form. This is a bit of an advanced topic; but it turns out that functions also form a `Monad` with `return = const`, and so `return f(b)` actually meant `const f(b)`, which threw away the `(b)` term. (Aside: in addition to being *allowed* to use the function instance of `Monad`, we also *must* be using the function instance of `Monad` here. Since we are applying `return f` to `(b)`, the type of `return f` must be a function.) So your definition was the same as:

```
mapIO' f a = do b <- a
                f
```

That is: first do `a`, throw away its result, then do `f` *as if it were another input/output action*. If you check the type inferred for `mapIO` you will see it matches this intuition:

```
mapIO :: Monad m => m b -> m t -> m b
```

Whoops!